# In python is there a reason to pass self to static method in a class?

Tags: python, instance-variables, class-variables

I was reviewing code at [One-Class Neural Network](https://github.com/raghavchalapathy/oc-nn/blob/master/src/models/OC_NN.py).

The author creates a `@staticmethod`:

```
@staticmethod
def custom_ocnn_loss(self,nu, w, V):
```

but later inside the `OC_NN` `fit` instance method, accesses it using the class name and passes in `self`:

```
model.compile(loss=OC_NN.custom_ocnn_loss(self,nu, w, V), optimizer=opt,metrics=None)
```

Is there a reason to do this (i.e. create `@staticmethod` which takes `self` as an argument and is accessed inside instance method using class name)?

Answer (score 3):

In the script, `custom_ocnn_loss` function has `@staticmethod` decorator which means it is not an instance method but a static method. The variable `self` might suggest differently, but when calling the `custom_ocnn_loss` function, the `self` variable is passed to it.

Comment: Yes, you're right `custom_ocnn_loss` s a `@staticmethod`.  However, why would you create a `@staticmethod` with `self` as an argument?  If you want a method in a class to have access to the object's instance, wouldn't you just use an instance method?

Comment: I tried to update my question as best I can.  It's not clear to me why the author would to this, so it's difficult for me to describe.  Thanks for your response.

Comment: Naming the variable `self` is against conventions and very misleading. I suspect that the author was unaware of that.

Comment: That depends on what you are expected to pass as the first argument. Just because the parameter is named `self` doesn't mean you *must* pass the "current object" as an argument.

Comment: I do not think that it is a good practice to use a `staticmethod` in this way. Judging by the code, it is possible that they originally intended for the custom_ocnn_loss function to be completely static with no dependence on instance attributes, but then after realizing that `r` was needed, they quickly added `self` to the method signature as an afterthought. It is also possible that they intended to use the function with other instances that have a `r` attribute, but that would be poor practice.

Comment: Thanks for responses.  They all make sense to me.  I was concerned there was something I was missing.  It sounds more like the author might just have done a few not quite "pythonic" implementations.